# Curve/soften edge of mesh with many faces?

Tags: mesh

How can I soften/curve the edge of this model? It currently has what is pretty close to a 90 degree angle but using the bevel and smooth tools have had little to no effect. I don't need it to be extremely smooth, even a 45 degree angle would work for me. Is it possible to do this without moving the edge by hand? Thanks for any help.

[image: The model in Object mode][image: The model in Edit mode]

Comment: your mesh is completely triangulated, if you want to work on it you should probably come back to a more classical mesh, i.e. quads and much less polygons

Comment: Select all and hit alt+j. This will pops up the left side menu where you can adjust a few things. If you are lucky you will get quads.